# Failure to launch AWS-EMR cluster in Frankfurt, but successful in N. Virginia

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

I'm trying to launch a small EMR cluster via the Java SDK for AWS. I'm trying, and failing miserably, to launch it in Frankfurt (eu-central-1), but successful when launching it in N. Virginia (us-east-1).

My configuration:

- macOS 10.12.1
- Java 1.8.102
- AWS SDK for Java 1.11.60
- Hadoop 2.7.3
- IntelliJ 2016.2.4

I have already verified the following:

1. The Instance Type that I'm requesting (`M1Medium`) exists in both regions.
2. The Hadoop version I'm requesting for the cluster (2.7.3) is the one that exists in the EMR version (5.2.0).
3. I have the appropriate `IAM Roles` to support the clusters (the default ones - `EMR_EC2_DefaultRole` & `EMR_DefaultRole`), and they obviously work correctly because they are used to launch the cluster in N. Virginia.
4. I have EC2 key pairs for both regions.
5. I have validated that EMR is available as a service in both regions.
6. I have validated that I'm using the correct availability zones for both regions, and that these zones are healthy, via the EC2 dashboard through my web browser.
7. For each cluster attempt, I'm using an S3 bucket at the same region for input, output and EMR logs.

This is the code to launch a cluster in Frankfurt:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    parseArgs(args);

    if (environment.equals("local")) {
        // Local machine, single node setup. Used in order to debug the M-R logic.
        String[] p1args = {"input", "output", environment};
        Phase1.main(p1args);
    } else {
        // EMR setup. This is the main intent of this app.
        AWSCredentials credentials = null;
        try {
            credentials = new ProfileCredentialsProvider().getCredentials();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AmazonClientException(
                    "Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. " +
                            "Please make sure that your credentials file is at the correct " +
                            "location (~/.aws/credentials), and is in valid format.",
                    e);
        }

        AmazonElasticMapReduce mapReduce = new AmazonElasticMapReduceClient(credentials);

        HadoopJarStepConfig jarStep1 = new HadoopJarStepConfig()
                .withJar("s3n://skill-finder-eu-central-1/jars/SkillFinder.jar")
                .withMainClass("Phase1")
                .withArgs("s3n://skill-finder-eu-central-1/input-10K", "s3n://skill-finder-eu-central-1/output-eu-central-1", environment);

        StepConfig step1Config = new StepConfig()
                .withName("Phase 1")
                .withHadoopJarStep(jarStep1)
                .withActionOnFailure("TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW");

        JobFlowInstancesConfig instances = new JobFlowInstancesConfig()
                .withInstanceCount(5)
                .withMasterInstanceType(InstanceType.M1Medium.toString())
                .withSlaveInstanceType(InstanceType.M1Medium.toString())
                .withHadoopVersion("2.7.3")
                .withEc2KeyName("AWS-EU-CENTRAL-1")
                .withKeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps(false)
                .withPlacement(new PlacementType("eu-central-1a"));

        RunJobFlowRequest runFlowRequest = new RunJobFlowRequest()
                .withName("skill-finder")
                .withInstances(instances)
                .withSteps(step1Config)
                .withJobFlowRole("EMR_EC2_DefaultRole")
                .withServiceRole("EMR_DefaultRole")
                .withReleaseLabel("emr-5.2.0")
                .withLogUri("s3n://skill-finder-eu-central-1/logs/")
                .withBootstrapActions();

        System.out.println("Submitting the JobFlow Request to Amazon EMR and running it...");
        RunJobFlowResult runJobFlowResult = mapReduce.runJobFlow(runFlowRequest);
        String jobFlowId = runJobFlowResult.getJobFlowId();
        System.out.println("Ran job flow with id: " + jobFlowId);
    }

}
```

When launching in N. Virginia, I just replace `eu-central-1` with `us-east-1`.

This is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.model.AmazonElasticMapReduceException: Specified Availability Zone is not supported. (Service: AmazonElasticMapReduce; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 578db9ad-b3bf-11e6-9a57-5179acb16d3f)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1545)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1183)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:964)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:676)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:650)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:633)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$300(AmazonHttpClient.java:601)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:583)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:447)
at com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.AmazonElasticMapReduceClient.doInvoke(AmazonElasticMapReduceClient.java:1469)
at com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.AmazonElasticMapReduceClient.invoke(AmazonElasticMapReduceClient.java:1445)
at com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.AmazonElasticMapReduceClient.runJobFlow(AmazonElasticMapReduceClient.java:1255)
at MRTaskLauncher.main(MRTaskLauncher.java:97)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Comment: Do you have a region specified in .aws/credentials ?

Comment: No, there's a single access key and secret access key under `[default]`.

Comment: Could you test adding `mapReduce.setEndpoint("https://elasticmapreduce.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com");` after mapReduce instantiation? (untested)

Comment: Tried, doesn't change the outcome - same exception is still thrown.

Comment: @Gonfva is exactly correct about the underlying cause, though the specific solution may be different.  There is -- obviously enough to everyone -- no availability zone called `eu-central-1a` in the `us-east-1` region, but understandably *much less obvious* is the fact that this is the actual reason you're getting the error, and that this code is implicitly sending the request to us-east-1, because that is the implicit behavior of the SDK.  That needs to be different, so we need to figure out how to configure it so that the request will be sent to eu-central-1.

Comment: As familiar as I am with the actual AWS APIs, my familiarity with Java SDK is limited, but I assume the answer can be found in [AWS Region Selection](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-region-selection.html) (which does seem to confirm my assertion that us-east-1 is the default region).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, I came to the same conclusion. At the moment the only thing that I can think of is some obscure bug that is invisible to me. I have manually set both the endpoint and the region (and also each one by itself) so the request would be sent to eu-central-1, but it seems that it always gets routed to us-east-1. I'm really at a loss of words, becuase on top of it, `Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1).isServiceSupported(AmazonElasticMapReduce.ENDPOINT_PREFIX)` evaluates to `true`.

Comment: Sorry for all the speculation, but what about using the [client builder](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/creating-clients.html) instead?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - tried it, same results. :(

Comment: As a last resort, I typed the endpoint name in `setEndpoint` instead of copy-pasting it from the comment above. I also retyped every string that references a region in the code above. Lo and behold - it all works now... Guess some weird characters were copied from here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found the solution: I launched the cluster with `M3Xlarge` instances instead of `M2Medium`. Works like a charm!

How I got to this:

1. Since I managed to launch clusters in N. Virginia with the default IAM roles for EMR, I started to think that I may have problems with authentication. This was further supported when I managed to launch a cluster in Frankfurt via CLI (found the example [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com//ElasticMapReduce/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-iam-roles-creatingroles.html) under `Create and Use IAM Roles with the AWS CLI`).
2. What I did next was trying to re-launch the cluster via the SDK. The cluster failed, but I copied the launch commands so I could launch via the CLI. To do this, I clicked on the cluster in the EMR cluster list (web interface), clicked on `View cluster details` and then at the button on the top row `AWS CLI export`.
3. To my amazement, the CLI provided much more specific error messages (in comparison with the web interface, which listed a validation error), which indicated that the culprit is the instance type! I then checked [here](https://aws.amazon.com/emr/pricing/) to find out which instances are available in Frankfurt, and selected one that didn't require VPC (M4 requires it), since I didn't have the energy to start messing with that stuff.
4. A bit of prelude - the listed validation error caused me to find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27953582/emr-service-role-is-invalid-when-creating-emr-cluster). It was this question that led me to research the issue of default IAM roles, and to try and use the CLI.